# How to override member of base class after inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

i have this :

```
class A {
    public :
        A(int i ) : m_S(i)
        {  
            m_Pa = new Foo(*this) ;
        }
    private :
        int m_S ;
        Foo* m_Pa;
}

and derived class 

class B : public A {
    public :
        B() : A (242) 
        {
          // here i like to override the A class m_Pa member but i don't know how to do it right 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your m_Pa should be protected than you can call like:

```
 B() : A (242), m_Pa(12) 
 {

 }
```

or

```
 B() : A (242)
 {
   m_PA = 55
 }
```

or you should make a public or protected function which changes m_Pa

```
 class A {
     public :
         A(int i ) : m_S(i)
         {  
              m_Pa = new Foo(*this) ;
         }

        void setPA(int val)
        {
             m_PA = val;
        }
```

Comment: when i try your first example im getting 
B : illegal member initialization: 'm_PA' is not a base or member

Comment: that is why you wrote m_Pa under private. you can not change a private member if it is not base class. you can only change protected or public members from a derived class.

also probably you wrote ":" instead of "," before m_Pa(new Foo(*this))

Answer (score 1):

What is m_Pa? You never had it declared. Assuming it's a private data member of  type Foo* in class A, you can't directly change it in the derived class unless you change A's interface. E.g., you can provide a protected setter member function:

```
class A {
....
protected:
 void setFoo(const Foo* foo);
}

class B {
 ....
 Foo *foo = new Foo(this);
 setFoo(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't override member variables in a derived class, only methods.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: By declaring `m_Pa` private, you are saying that only `class A` should be able to modify it. So you cannot alter its value using methods of `class B`.

Longer answer: In C++ (and most other object oriented programming languages), you not only declare the type of a member, but also its visibility (`public`, `protected` and `private`). This allows you to enfore encapsulation of data: You only expose an interface, but you do not let clients of your class modify its internals directly.

In your concrete example, I would create accessors

```
Foo* getPa() {
  return m_Pa;
}

void setPa(Foo* Pa) {
  m_Pa = Pa;
}
```

in `class A` and use them in `class B` to modify `m_Pa`. If you would like `class B` (but not unrelated classes) to be able to modify `m_Pa` declare `getPa()` and `setPa()` in a  `protected:` section of your class; if you would like any client to modify them declare them in a `public:` section. Especially in the later case you need to start worrying about object ownership, i.e. which object is responsible for deleting the object stored in `m_Pa` which is created in the constructor. A practical solution to this problem is to use smart pointers, see for instance [boost's implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

A note on terminology: "Overriding" a member in C++ usually refers to giving a new implementation of a `virtual` member function. So if your `class A` has a method

```
virtual void doIt()
```

then a member of the same type in `class B` overrides the implementation of `A`'s `doIt()`.